# Test with older versions of Firefox

Tags: firefox, testing

I had a situation where a user saw an error on her browser which is Firefox. It might be an older version. Is there a way to test multiple versions of Firefox without downloading a bunch of them?

Comment: Some more information around your question : http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox and https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this. I have gone through multiple links to find its solution. For example you want to install firefox 4.0 but want to keep 3.6 as well then you need to install Firefox 4.0 using the Custom Installation option, in a uniquely named folder — like `/Program Files/Firefox 4.0/` — don't let 4.0 run after the installation procedure is complete.

Create a new profile exclusively for the 4.0 beta version and create a desktop shortcut with `-P "profile"` appended to the target to launch that profile.

Helpful links will be [link1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/797010) and [link2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936867).

During the search I have also found one software [utilu](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/install-multiple-versions-of-firefox-with-utilu-mozilla-firefox-collection-developers/) that may be useful, but clearly speaking I have not tried that yet, will try later.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Utili Mozilla Firefox collection if you want to test your site in different versions of Firefox. It's really convenient - a lot of versions in one pack.

http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/

(I'm not associated with this company)

cheers

Answer (score 6):

I have a folder `/browsers` with custom versions of browsers, e.g. firefox, chrome, opera.

Then launch the different version when you need to test a specific version rather than launching the default one from your Applications.

*e.g. just rename the installed .app.

*Chromium.app* rename to e.g. **Chromium_19.app**  *need to disable auto-updates*

*Firefox.app* rename to **Firefox_38.app**

- [firefox releases](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)
- [Chrome releases](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html)
- [Opera releases](ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/mac/)
- [Multi Safari](https://michelf.ca/projects/multi-safari/)

Comment: If you are looking for the last Firefox release to run on macOS 10.12-10.14 the answer [according to Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-users-macos-1012-1013-1014-moving-to-extended-support) is Firefox 115 and it can be downloaded directly from [Mozilla](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/115.9.1esr/mac/).

Comment: If you are looking for the last Chromium release to officially support macOS 10.13 the answer [according to Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/10314655) is Chromium 113 (Chromium 114-117 _may_ work, but macOS 10.13 is already deprecated) and it can be downloaded either directly from the official [Google Server](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/1121498/) (chrome-mac.zip).

Comment: Determining the [folder number](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/) of a certain Chromium release number [is a bit of a pain](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/releases?platform=Mac), so there may be a release that is slighly newer than the one linked. Otherwise there is an apparently trustworthy [third-party project](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) which also offers a build of [Chrome 113](https://github.com/macchrome/macstable/releases/tag/v113.5672.126-M113.0.5672.126-r1121455-macOS) (Chromium.app.ungoogled-113.0.5672.126.tar.xz).

Answer (score 2):

there sites like these http://browsershots.org/. They let you test browsers without downloading.

Comment: I know about this one but for the site that i am testing, I have to login to see the page I want. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OSX using Homebrew, you can install via brew cask:

```
brew tap goldcaddy77/firefox
brew cask install firefox-46
```

More info can be found at the git repo [homebrew-firefox](https://github.com/goldcaddy77/homebrew-firefox)